# JAVASCRIPT/Chrome: How to Get Extension of Page

Tags: javascript

Given

```
google.com
```

How can I get **.com** and save it to a variable. I was thinking of using regex to split google.com into google and ".com", but I don't know the regex to do this.

It might help to know that I got the hostname from using *window.location.hostname*

Thank you!

Comment: `var str = "google.com"; alert(str.split(".")[1]);` Change `1` to the size of the array if there's multiple dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the location by `.`, and the last value in the array will be the extension.  Something like this would work:

```
var extension=location.hostname.split(".");
extension=extension[extension.length-1];

console.log(extension)
```

JS Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/yvy0zrat/

Hope that helps!

Comment: This returns `uk` for `bbc.co.uk`, where the answer probably should be `co.uk `

Comment: Possibly, `co.uk` is a second level domain.  OP would need to clarify if he was interested in that or just TLD.

Comment: Check the title, one might assume that by 'extension' OP means what's the entire domain after subtracting the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a substring and lastIndexof:

```
var str =  window.location.hostname;
var ending = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/06r86q0n/

Mostly the same as the other answer, but neither helps with double domains like ".co.uk"

Comment: This returns `uk` for `bbc.co.uk`, where the answer probably should be `co.uk `

Comment: @Matsemann Lol I'm not sure if your comment or my edit came first, but that's right. It would be best to check using a regex of all known host suffix and see which one matches the hostname

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **split**, its a bit slower than **slice**:

```
var last = location.hostname
var t = last.slice(last.lastIndexOf("."));


console.log(t) // .com, .net etc...
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qu0rffb/

Comment: This returns `uk` for `bbc.co.uk`, where the answer probably should be `co.uk `

Comment: nice catch! now this is suddenly a much tougher question, even with a regex

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create a regex statement that will only grab the `.com` then I would use something like:

`/(.com)/` as your Regex statement

so your code would look like something like this:

`var regexMatch = /(.com)/;` as a regular expression literal

or

`var regexMatch = new RegExp(".com");` as constructor function of the RegExp object.

Comment: what if its .net, .co, .whatever?

Comment: His question asks for a regex statement that grabs a ".com".

Comment: Then that could be solved by doing `var a = '.com' `, ;)

Comment: His question states `How to Get Extension of Page`, not `.com`  in particular imo